# Connect to remote MongoDB instance from ASP.NET

Tags: .net, rest, mongodb, connection-string

I'm having some trouble nutting out why I'm unable to connect to a new database I've created at MongoHQ.

I want to include the correct connection string in my Web.config file and have my Mongo object refer to that for the database connection.

The connection strings (edited, obviously) are:

> Public Access
>
> mongo flame.mongohq.com:27065/dunedin -u {username} -p {password}
>
> AWS Internal Access
>
> mongo flame.local.mongohq.com:27065/dunedin -u {username} -p {password}

Obviously, I've included my correct username in password in place of the placeholders in the braces.

My code is:

```
string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBMongo"].ConnectionString;
var mongo = new Mongo(connection);

mongo.Connect();
```

However, as soon as I try to instantiate that Mongo object, I get a format exception saying

> Invalid connection string on:

What is that connection string supposed to look like for remotely-hosted MongoDB instances?

**EDIT:**

The Connection String entry in Web.Config is

```
<add name="DBMongo" connectionString="mongo flame.mongohq.com:27065/dunedin -u ausername -p apassword"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `mongo shell`, type `show users`. Then use the hashed password this displays for your password in the connection string.

Answer (score 6):

The connection string for MongoDB is formatted as a URI, details [can be found here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/). Below is the basic format and some examples:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][/[database][?options]]

mongodb://127.0.0.1 

mongodb://127.0.0.1/mydatabase

mongodb://mongosrv.com:10230/mydatabase

mongodb://myadmin:secretpass@mongosrv.com:10230/mydatabase

// Or in your case it would be 

mongodb://ausername:apassword@flame.mongohq.com:27065/dunedin
```

You can also use MongoUrlBuilder and MongoUrl to construct or parse the connection string programatticaly. Though a bit wordy, I believe the recommended usage goes like this

```
var mongoUrl = new MongoUrl(settings.ConnectionString);
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoUrl);
var mongoServer = mongoClient.GetServer();
var mongoDatabase = mongoServer.GetDatabase(mongoUrl.DatabaseName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are obviously using mongodb-csharp.  What you are using most definately is not a valid connection string.  You can ask your question at the group http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-csharp or look at the docs and code here.  There is even a connection string builder so you don't need to know the exact syntax.

Comment: Couldn't find the connection string builder, but that site had the information I needed.  Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

How does your connection string placed in Web.config look like? Exception you get indicates that it's invalid. Clarify it using MongoDB documentation.

Comment: The documentation on the Mongo site (that I've found) hasn't been that helpful for remote connections.  It's primarily centred around working from the command line.

Comment: @Phil.Wheele: I found this: http://www.captaincodeman.com/2010/05/24/mongodb-azure-clouddrive/ which leads to http://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp