# Pointing Simple Membership provider to use MongoDB Connection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

In MVC4 application I pointed Simple Membership provider to `MongoDB` Connection. But it is throwing error with connection string.

Here is my code

**Web.config**

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;database=user" />
 <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

**Global.asax**

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "Users", "Id", "Username", autoCreateTables: true);
```

**SimpleMembershipProvider**

```
 public class SimpleMongoMembershipProvider : SimpleMembershipProvider
 {
    public override string CreateAccount(string userName, string password)
    {
        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(userName,password, new { Gender = "Mal", DOB = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1), Email = "mymy@trtr.com" });
        return base.CreateAccount(userName, password);
    }
 }
```

**Account Controller**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var db = new SimpleMongoMembershipProvider();
        db.CreateAccount("admin", "admin");

        return View();
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Any other step needs to be followed to point MongoDB as Connection

Comment: What is the exact error it is throwing?

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be authenticating or passing credentials to Mongo DB, you need to authenticate to the Mongo DB database, there are several different ways to do this depending on your usage, use the instructions outlined here: 
http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/authenticate-with-csharp-driver/

Comment: There is also some good discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091946/connect-to-remote-mongodb-instance-from-asp-net

Comment: Thanks, But I am having access to MongoDB without any credentials